# Check if the JSON from the Response is NULL or not

Tags: json, salesforce, odata, apex, json-deserialization

I am trying to check if the response from the API GET method is Null. The response is like

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://dev.com/data/$metadata#Customers",
    "value": []
}
```

I need to check if the value array is null or not and do the necessary steps below is what I tried

```
public class deserializeData
{
    public String @odata_context {get;set;} // in json: @odata.context
    public List<Value> value {get;set;}
}

public class getDataFromExternalSystem{
  public string getDataFrom(){
    .......
    Http http1 = new Http();
    HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
    req1.setEndpoint(endPoint);
    req1.setMethod('GET');
    req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+atoken);
    HttpResponse res1 = http1.send(req1);
    System.debug('Response Body=========' + res1.getBody());

    deserializeData dsData = (deserializeData)JSON.deserialize(res1.getbody(),deserializeData.class);

    if(dsData.value.size = null) {
       ......
    }
    else{
       ......
    }}
```

But I get below error like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`@odata_context` is not a legal identifier in Apex. `@` is used to introduce annotations.

If you're using JSON2Apex, which appears to be the case, you'll need to change the name of the property to something legal for Apex (like `odata_context`), and make the corresponding change in the parser method. E.g., where JSON2Apex generates

```
                if (text == '@odata.context') {
                    @odata_context = parser.getText();
```

you'll need to replace that identifier with the new one you choose.